# Horizontal Scrollbar Unintended Body Overflow

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling

I have spent many hours trying to fix this problem but with no luck.

When I decrease the resolution a horizontal scrollbar appears and I can't find which element is out of the box causing this issue.

I'm using a bootstrap theme and I have inserted some CSS code inside this bootstrap theme, I have also replaced some sections with my own.

When I delete all nodes except from the footer I don't have the horizontal scroll bar issue so I believe I have done more than 1 mistakes. I also tried to have 1 section at the time and still the issue persists. Right now I'm out of options really need help to fix that issue that holds me back.

`You can check it here` **https://jsfiddle.net/28rxv53a/**

The images will not work cause I'm using Jekyll and they point to my GH-PAGE.

**overflow-x:hidden** isn't a solution for my problem.

**EDITED**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/LazPap/assets/css/custom.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>LazPap - Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS - Includes Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Fade-in and Fade-out Plugin -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <!-- Modaal Plugin for contact link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Modaal/0.4.4/css/modaal.min.css"/>

  </head>
  <body id="page-top">
    <header class="masthead-background">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="parallax-window"><h1 class="background-text" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300" data-aos-duration="1000">LazPap</h1></div>
        <div id="scene">
          <div class="layer parallax-window" data-depth="0.5" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="HTML_5.png">
            <img src="/LazPap/images/HTML_5.png" class="background-image-left" />
          </div>
          <div class="layer" data-depth="-0.5">
            <img src="/LazPap/images/CSS_3.png" class="background-image-right" />
          </div>
          <div class="layer" data-depth="0.5">
            <img src="/LazPap/images/Javascript.png" class="background-image-under" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="page-section masthead-under-background">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center mx-auto">
          <h2 class="text-white mt-0 line-height text-heading" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="500">This project designed with Ruby on Rails</h2>
          <hr class="divider light my-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="650" />
          <p class="text-white mb-5 text-sub" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="800">For this Rails app project have used a variety of Rails Gems and Javascript - jQuery Libraries and differnt CSS animations.</p>
            <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="1000">
              <img src="/LazPap/images/Ruby_On_Rails.png" class="icon-ruby" />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

<p><!-- About Section --></p>
<section class="page-section" id="work">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
        <h1 class="work-text" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="500">My Wordpress Work</h1>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 text-center container-grid">
          <div data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="800">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="content">
                <h2>01</h2>
                <h3>Bazagiazi</h3>
                <a href="https://bazagiazi.com/">Visit</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="1200">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="content">
                <h2>02</h2>
                <h3>Empty</h3>
                <a href="#work">Stay Here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="1000">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="content">
                <h2>03</h2>
                <h3>Empty</h3>
                <a href="#work">Stay Here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

<p><!-- Contact Section --></p>
<section class="page-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
          <h1 class="mt-0 text-heading purple-text" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="500">Let's Get In Touch!</h1>
          <hr class="divider my-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="600" />
          <p class="text-muted mb-5 text-sub" data-aos="zoom-out-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="800">Feel free to contact me for any questions I'll glad to answer you as soon as i can!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ml-auto text-center mb-5 mb-lg-0">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x mb-3 text-muted" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="1000"></i>
          <a class="d-block text-sub" href="mailto:lazospap3@gmail.com" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-delay="1200">lazospap3@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btnScrollToTop" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300" data-aos-duration="1000">
      <i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
    </button>
  </section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const btnScrollToTop = document.getElementById("btnScrollToTop");
    btnScrollToTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
    });
  </script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<p><!--Heading Text translateY movement-->
  <script type="text/javascript" defer="">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollval = $(this).scrollTop();
      $(".background-text").css("transform",'translateY('+-scrollval/1.5+'%)');
    });
  </script></p>

<script defer="">
    var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    var parallax = new Parallax(scene);
  </script>

<script defer="">
    AOS.init();
  </script>


      <!--Modaal script -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"> <img src="/LazPap/images/Logo.png " class="logo-image"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#work">Work</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger modaal" data-modaal-type="inline" data-modaal-animation="fade" href="#inline" data-modaal-height="500">Contact</a>
                <div id="inline" style="display:none;">
                    <h2 class="modaal-heading">Contact Me</h2>
                    <h1 class="modaal-heading"><a class="d-block" href="mailto:lazospap3@gmail.com">lazospap3@gmail.com</a></h1>
                    </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/modaal@0.4.4/dist/js/modaal.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".inline").modaal();
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $("body").niceScroll({
          cursorcolor:"#fb6542",
          cursorwidth:"12",
          cursorborder: "none",
          cursorborderradius: 4,
          scrollspeed: 10,
        });
      </script>
    <footer class="bg-light py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="small text-center text-muted text-sub">Copyright &copy; 2019 - LazPap</div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/js/creative.min.js"></script>
    <!--CDN for Scroll opacity -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" defer>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $(window).scroll(function(){
           if($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
             $(".background-image-left").css({"opacity" : "0"})
             $(".background-image-right").css({"opacity" : "0"})
             $(".background-image-under").css({"opacity" : "0"})
             $(".background-text").css({"opacity" : "0"})
             $("#btnScrollToTop").css({"opacity" : "1"})
           }
           else {
             $(".background-image-left").css({"opacity" : "1"})
             $(".background-image-right").css({"opacity" : "1"})
             $(".background-image-under").css({"opacity" : "1"})
             $(".background-text").css({"opacity" : "1"})
             $("#btnScrollToTop").css({"opacity" : "0"})
           }
         })
       })
     </script>
     <!--Heading Text translateY movement-->
     <script type="text/javascript" defer>
       $(window).scroll(function() {
         var scrollval = $(this).scrollTop();
         $(".background-text").css("transform",'translateY('+-scrollval/1.5+'%)');
       });
     </script>

     <script defer>
       var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
       var parallax = new Parallax(scene);
     </script>

     <script defer>
       AOS.init();
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#btnScrollToTop{
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e62739;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
#btnScrollToTop:active{
  background: #cc2333;
}
.purple-text {
  color: #5a19b5;
}
.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0 40px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}
.container-grid .box {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  background: #060c21;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container-grid .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skew(2deg,2deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.container-grid .box:nth-child(1):before {
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, #ff0057, #e64a19);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
.container-grid .box:nth-child(2):before {
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, #89ff00, #00bcd4);
}
.container-grid .box:nth-child(3):before {
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, #e91e63, #5d02ff);
}
.container-grid .box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}
.box .content h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -140px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.box:hover .content h2 {
  top: -210px;
}
.box .content h3 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.box .content a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.box:hover .content a {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.box .content a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.work-text {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #5a19b5;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.bg-work {
  background-color: #e7eeed;
}
.modaal-heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 115px;
}
.text-sub{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.text-heading {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 34px;
}
.background-text {
    text-align: center;
    left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
    color: #fff55a;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    font-size: 90px;
}
 .logo-image {
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
 }
 .masthead-background {
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 500px;
   background-image: url("{{ '/images/Under_Background.png' | prepend: site.baseurl }}");
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: scroll;
 }
.masthead-under-background {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-image: url("{{ '/images/Under_Background.png' | prepend: site.baseurl }}");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
 .background-image-left {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 10%;
   transition: .8s;
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
   height: auto;
 }

 .background-image-right {
   top: 50%;
   left: 700px;
   position: relative;
   transition: .8s;
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
   height: auto;
 }
 .background-image-under {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 450px;
    transition: .8s;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    height: auto;
 }
.icon-ruby {
  position:relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
.icon-ruby:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.line-height {
  line-height: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .icon-ruby{width: 60%;}
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .background-image-left{width: 30%;}
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .background-image-under {
    width: 50%;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .background-image-right {
    width: 48%;
    left: 250px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .background-image-left {
    width: 22%;
    left: 10px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .background-image-under {
    width: 60%;
    left: 250px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .background-image-right {
    width: 50%;
    left: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .background-image-left {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .background-image-under {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .background-image-right {
    width: 70%;
    left: 500px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .background-text {
    left: 10px;
  }
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .background-text {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .background-text {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .background-text {
    font-size: 180px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .background-text {
    font-size: 220px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .modaal-heading{
    font-size:7vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible, please put your code directly in the question. Having external links (which may expire) will be of no help to anyone when this happens, also people are much less likely to look over your code if it requires clicking external links. So to both help people in the future & get a better response rate; please post your code in the question.

Comment: I updated with the HTML and CSS code as you requested.